# Does a Bluetooth Keyboard work with Windows Phone?

Tags: lumia, keyboard, bluetooth

I bought a Mini bluetooth Keyboard for my Nokia Lumia 710. But it doesn't seem to work.

Is there any way to get a bluetooth keyboard to work with Windows Phone 7.5?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As far as I can remember they haven't brought their bluetooth stack to this level yet. So I think that the answer here is no:(

[Here](http://gadgetix.com/2010/12/31/bluetooth-keyboards-on-windows-phone-7/) is also a link about this...