# How to change physical Bluetooth keyboard layout on Windows 10 Mobile?

Tags: windows-10-mobile, bluetooth, keyboard, lumia-950

I've connected my Lumia with Windows 10 Mobile to a Bluetooth keyboard. It works fine, but... Windows is using one keyboard layout standard (ABNT Brazilian standard) while the keyboard is USA International standard.

It's so easy to fix it on desktop Windows, but I'm not finding a way to do it on Windows 10 Mobile.

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to change the keyboard language?
Then go to **Settings> Devices> Keyboards> Add Keyboards**. This should work for all devices.

If it does not work after that, then read [this.](https://windowsphone.stackexchange.com/questions/896/does-a-bluetooth-keyboard-work-with-windows-phone?rq=1) The keyboard language may still not be supported.